# I am trying to login in to Microsoft Teams and after login app is not responding

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft

I am trying login in Microsoft Teams app and after i enter my email id and clik on sign in my teams app doesnt respond

I tried to clear the temp app data of teams tried every possible way and i am not sure what is the issue.

I tired to login in other Machine and i could successfully log on to it but not with my work machine. Could someone help

[image]

[image]

Comment: seems like machine related issue. Which operating system is it. Do you have the error message?

Comment: Windows 10 and i got a confirmation that teams admin revoked my token and hence the issue

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed this article? It is a good place to start.

Article:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/why-am-i-having-trouble-signing-in-to-microsoft-teams-a02f683b-61a3-4008-9447-ee60c5593b0f

Comment: Thank you for the link and sorry i forgot to update the error properly and i am attaching the error code

Comment: I'm not familiar with that error code, a quick google point to file corruption though. Maybe run running a system file check or try reinstalling the program??? Maybe copy that dll over from the computer that worked, backing up the original file beforehand so you can revert back if it does no work.

Comment: So I got to see the same time security log errors and we need to change the permissions HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AppID\{9CA88EE3-ACB7-47c8-AFC4-AB702511C276} by going there need to allow the domain admins then try to restart the machine and logon to the team desktop app